# 4G USB dongle recognized as wired network

Tags: networking, gnome, usb, network-interface, networkmanager

I have just bought a 4G USB dongle: paired with a SIM, it brings you 4G internet connection by creating a Wi-Fi network;
it is powered via USB port (power adapter or computer ports, does not matter).

Problem is: if I plug it in my laptop, the dongle gets recognized as (not-working) wired network;

How can I disable this behaviour?

in a few word, I want it does not get mounted/recognized
in other words, I want USB port providing just power, nothing else
like Android, where it let you choose *how manage the connection (charging-only, MIDI, MTP, photos)* when you connect the USB cable to computer

---

I am using Arch Linux w/ GNOME 44.2

---

FURTHER:
`lsusb` reports:

```
Bus 002 Device 033: ID 05c6:f00e Qualcomm, Inc. Android
```

when I connect the dongle, `journactl` says:

```
Jun 14 23:31:09 arch-xps kernel: usb 2-2: new high-speed USB device number 33 using xhci_hcd
Jun 14 23:31:09 arch-xps kernel: usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=05c6, idProduct=f00e, bcdDevice=ff.ff
Jun 14 23:31:09 arch-xps kernel: usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Jun 14 23:31:09 arch-xps kernel: usb 2-2: Product: Android
Jun 14 23:31:09 arch-xps kernel: usb 2-2: Manufacturer: Android
Jun 14 23:31:09 arch-xps kernel: usb 2-2: SerialNumber: 0123456789ABCDEF
Jun 14 23:31:09 arch-xps NetworkManager[377]: <info>  [1686778269.1658] manager: (usb0): new Ethernet device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/6)
Jun 14 23:31:09 arch-xps kernel: rndis_host 2-2:1.0 usb0: register 'rndis_host' at usb-0000:00:14.0-2, RNDIS device, b6:99:e7:48:ad:83
Jun 14 23:31:09 arch-xps mtp-probe[85412]: checking bus 2, device 33: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2"
Jun 14 23:31:09 arch-xps mtp-probe[85412]: bus: 2, device: 33 was not an MTP device
Jun 14 23:31:09 arch-xps kernel: rndis_host 2-2:1.0 enp0s20u2: renamed from usb0
Jun 14 23:31:09 arch-xps NetworkManager[377]: <info>  [1686778269.7719] device (usb0): interface index 6 renamed iface from 'usb0' to 'enp0s20u2'
Jun 14 23:31:09 arch-xps NetworkManager[377]: <info>  [1686778269.7814] device (enp0s20u2): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

What the firmware of that dongle (by the way, quite possibly a Linux-running device itself!) decides to do when plugged in to a USB host is up to the firmware.

So, if it decides to present itself as network interface, that's what it's going to do. Nothing forces you to use that device!

You can of course use a USB extension cord with the data lines severed to provide +5V and GND instead of a USB connection, but be warned that this also means that the device cannot negotiate higher current than the standards-guaranteed 150 mA and might hence lead to the USB bus shutting the port power down, assuming something has shorted.

Comment: I added some info in OP; yes I can simply use a smartphone charger but I think there is a software solution, since the kernel and **networkmanager** take care of it

Comment: as said, nothing forces you (or NetworkManager) to use the network device that appears, but you cannot stop it from appearing, as long as you connect it to your USB host. That's how USB works. You don't have to do anything, just don't (try to) use the network card. That's all there is to it.